# How am I supposed to update an array of objects state with a filtered version of that array in Vue 3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have a component which listens for an emit, and then tries to filter out the user with userId out of the users state. The problem is that just trying to assign filteredUsers to users does not seem to work.

```
<script setup>
    import UsersTable from '../components/UsersTable.vue';
    import UserForm from '../components/UserForm.vue';
    import { reactive } from 'vue';

    let users = reactive([]);

    const onUserDelete = (userId) => {
        const filteredUsers = users.filter((user) => user.id !== userId);

        users = filteredUsers;
    }
</script>

<template>
    <div class="home">
        <UsersTable v-if="users.length > 0" :users="users" @on-user-delete="onUserDelete" />
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: What does "does not work" mean exactly? Is there an error or unexpected result? Syntactically, the code seems fine. There's a lot of places where something can potentially go wrong, and it's not clear based on just the code where a problem might be. Please, narrow it down. You'll need to try debugging and provide more information.  Does the emit fire? Does the method `onUserDelete` get called? What are the values of users and userId?  What is the result of the filter operation?

Comment: @yoduh I'm not getting any console errors and filteredUsers is what I expect it to be, it just seems that the assigntment to the state is not working for whatever reason. onUserDelete is getting called with the correct userId.

Comment: Read [limitations of Reactive point 2](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html#limitations-of-reactive) - I suspect you're replacing the entire object (well, more than suspect reading your code) - it is recommended you use `ref` instead for what you are doing

Comment: alternatively `users.splice(0, users.length, ...filteredUsers)` may work, not sure, never bothered trying that way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> always use `const` for react variables you must never change it

Here you have the following solutions:

**Costly**

```js
<script setup>
    import UsersTable from '../components/UsersTable.vue';
    import UserForm from '../components/UserForm.vue';
    import { ref } from 'vue';

    const users = ref([]);

    const onUserDelete = (userId) => {
        const filteredUsers = users.value.filter((user) => user.id !== userId);

        users.value = filteredUsers;
    }
</script>
```

**Save**

```js
<script setup>
    import UsersTable from '../components/UsersTable.vue';
    import UserForm from '../components/UserForm.vue';
    import { reactive } from 'vue';

    const users = reactive([]);

    const onUserDelete = (userId) => {
        users.splice(users.findIndex(item => item.id === userId) >>> 0, 1)
    }
</script>
```

**Very costly**

```js
<script setup>
    import UsersTable from '../components/UsersTable.vue';
    import UserForm from '../components/UserForm.vue';
    import { ref } from 'vue';

    const users = reactive([]);

    const onUserDelete = (userId) => {
        const filteredUsers = users.filter((user) => user.id !== userId);

        users.splice(0)
        users.push(...filteredUsers)
    }
</script>
```